# How can weight be equal in the equivalence principle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, equivalence-principle

According to Einstein, weight will be the same as here in earth in a rocket going at 1G far from gravity fields. If we propulse an object here it will feel two forces, F=mg and F=ma of the thrust, but in space it will only feel the force of thrust, so how can two forces equal one? how can weight be the same?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence principle concludes that the gravitational force you experience here on earth, in a *stationary* frame of reference (you are standing still with respect to the earth’s surface) is equal to the force you would feel if you were in a uniformly accelerated frame of reference in space, where the acceleration is $g$.

In other words, if you weighed yourself on earth and did the same in this uniformly accelerated frame, you would get the same result.

The equivalence principle does *not* make a comparison between an object accelerated on earth compared to the same in space. Instead the comparison is made with an object *stationary* on the earth’s surface and one that is uniformly accelerated in space at the rate of $g\ ms^{-2}$. This is where your misinterpretation occurs. Since this implies that $$m_G\times g = m_i \times a_g$$ then one concludes that $$m_G=m_i$$ since $g=a_g$ or that $$m_G=m_i$$ meaning gravitational mass and inertial mass are equivalent.

That is the essence of Einstein’s principle of equivalence.

Comment: Sorry i still can't understand it. Is it because the equivalence principle doesn't consider that gravity is a force? therefore if gravity is a real force i'm right in what i'm saying?

Comment: Yes, this correct. Einstein’s general relativity does indeed consider gravity as _not_ being a force as such, but an inertial force, arising from spacetime curvature. Objects follow geodesics, making it appear as though there is the classical Newtonian gravitational force. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Forget g's and accelerations and forces for a moment, and simply imagine the following scenario.  Really do close your eyes and imagine it.
You go inside an elevator and shut the door.  The power goes out so you cannot change floors.  You can jump, do push-ups, toss a tennis ball, any experiment you can think of. (And the elevator is perfectly rigid so there is no bouncing).  Then someone tells you the elevator is actually in intergalactic space, being pulled forward (what you call "up") at 9.8 m/s^2, and there is no gravity. What action could you take to prove them right or wrong?

Then suddenly, the rope snaps.  Your stomach feels like it's gone to your throat.  You are falling, your tennis ball is weightless in the air. But this person tells you there is no gravity, you are in intergalactic space, and the elevator is no longer being pulled. What action could you take to prove them right or wrong?

This is the equivalence principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion as to what the two cases are.  The actual two cases:

1. A weight here on Earth (no rocket), $F = mg$
2. A weight on a rocket (far from Earth, i.e. no gravity) under going acceleration, $F = ma$

If the acceleration of the rocket is the same as the gravitation acceleration of the Earth's gravity, $a = g$, then the experienced force will be the same.

Comment: If we propulse an object here it will feel two forces, gravity and propulsion.  If we propulse an object far from any gravitational field it will feel only the force of propulsion so how can weight be the same?

Comment: @Wolf98 there’s no propulsion in the Earthbound case

Comment: to make an object "levitate" you need the same force of the weight acting down the object, so it's f=ma acting two times in the object in opposite direction, something that doesn't happen in space because there is no gravity